# How to expose a Horizon URL

Tags: horizon, stellar-laboratory

I created a private network using only `stellar-core`, but I'm finding it increasing difficult to work with the network without SDK support. This can be all solved if I can use `stellar-lab` with my private network.

I see that I can interact with a custom network using the `custom` button on top right corner of [stellar-lab](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/), which requires a `network-passphrase` and a `Horizon URL`. I know my `network-passphrase` but have no idea how to setup my `Horizon URL` or what that even is. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Interaction with Stellar (-based) blockchain should be done via Horizon.

You need to deploy horizon server and set up it to your stellar-core node.

1. Build it from repo https://github.com/stellar/horizon or use prebuilt binaries.
2. Bind Horizon ports to External IP:port behind url with SSL certificate.
3. In Stellar Laboratory you can add custom url: https://yourhorizon.com:port/ and use it as testnet/mainnet.

Comment: BTW, if you plan to work with historical data (not just posting transactions), you should run Horizon with option --ingest=true